# I need to fetch Row twice in SQL from Single Table

Tags: mysql, sql

[Expected Result]

I Need this result from Single table dont know how to do this.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to do that in SQL? If you want to display the rows twice, do it in the presentation code.

Answer (score 1):

One simple method is:

```
select t.*
from t
union all
select t.*
from t;
```

If you care about the ordering, then you need an `order by` clause, so add:

```
order by custname;
```

Comment: I tried this but It is combining same table One by on as expected, but imy expectation is Same Ids should be displayed together

Answer (score 1):

You can use `union all` to duplicate each and every row in the resultset:

```
select custname, city from mytable
union all select custname, city from mytable
```

An `order by` clause might be useful:

```
select custname, city from mytable
union all select custname, city from mytable
order by custname, city
```

Comment: I tried this but  It is combining same table One by on as expected, but imy expectation is Same Ids should be displayed together

Comment: @manishdubey: just use `order by`. See my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add `ORDER BY` to the `UNION`. For example:

```
select * from t union all select * from t order by id
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/aaGyjYzP7sBtAPXe5nN3n4/0).

Comment: @Barmar I respectfully disagree.

Comment: Great .. It Works Thanks